# How to create Checkboxes from list

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter

I'm trying to make a very basic program right now that will show a window, and group of Checkboxs vertically in a labelframe. I want the Checkboxes to automatically generate based on the contents of a list. I found an entry from someone on here with a similar desire and copied his code, but I'm getting the error: "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

I'm new to Python, tried everything to correct this but coming up short. Any help would be great! Full code below:

```
from tkinter import *

#list to be used to make Checkboxes
pg = ["goal1","goal2"]


class yeargoals:
global pg
def __init__(self,master):
    self.master = master
    master.title("This Year's Goals")

    #Makes the label Fram I want the Checkboxes to go in
    self.LabelFramep= LabelFrame()
    self.LabelFramep.configure(width=210)

    #Makes the Checkboxs from the list above
    for goal in pg:
        pg[goal] = Variable()
        l = Checkbutton(self.LabelFramep, text=goal, variable=pg[goal])
        l.pack()


root = Tk()
Window = yeargoals(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The error message is pretty straightforward; your variable that you're using for the list indicies is a string, and it needs to be cast to an int first. I haven't really looked through your code, but just off the top of my head, it might be the `goal` variable that's giving you the issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop `for goal in pg:` will already give you each goal text in the variable `goal`:

```
>>> pg = ["goal1","goal2"]
>>> for goal in pg:
...   print goal
...
goal1
goal2
```

When you do `pg[goal]`, that's trying to lookup the index `"goal1"` in a list, which is an error. So text is already `goal` (which you have) and variable just needs to be a new variable.

```
for goal in pg:
    l = Checkbutton(self.LabelFramep, text=goal, variable=Variable())
    l.pack()
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! Quick follow-up, when I do it this way is there still a way for me to check the status of each checkbox? The ultimate goal here is to not only have these created, but when one is checked to have a total amount increased by 1.

Comment: If you want to count checkboxes, use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) like this: `for i, goal in enumerate(pg, start=1)`. Then `i` has running index, which starts at `0` (I've done `start=1` since you want a count).

Answer (score 0):

Below example produces the simplest class I can think of that creates [check buttons](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm) off of a list:

```
import tkinter as tk

class CheckbuttonList(tk.LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, master, text=None, list_of_cb=None):
        super().__init__(master)

        self['text'] = text
        self.list_of_cb = list_of_cb
        self.cb_values = dict()
        self.check_buttons = dict()

        if self.list_of_cb:
            for item in list_of_cb:
                self.cb_values[item] = tk.BooleanVar()
                self.check_buttons[item] = tk.Checkbutton(self, text=item)
                self.check_buttons[item].config(onvalue=True, offvalue=False,
                                            variable=self.cb_values[item])
                self.check_buttons[item].pack()



if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()

    my_list = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]

    my_cbs = CheckbuttonList(root, "My Checkbox List", my_list)
    my_cbs.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```