# How can I make a checklist with checkboxes?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a checklist with checkboxes that I can click by clicking the checkboxes.

I tried some code from [How to create Checkboxes from list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48084772/how-to-create-checkboxes-from-list), but it gives me an error. I know how to code some *basic* programs, but not more complex ones. This is my code:

```
     import tkinter as tk

     class CheckbuttonList(tk.LabelFrame):
         def __init__(self, master, text=None, list_of_cb=None):
             super().__init__(master)

             self['text'] = text
             self.list_of_cb = list_of_cb
             self.cb_values = dict()
             self.check_buttons = dict()
 
             if self.list_of_cb:
                 for item in list_of_cb:
                     self.cb_values[item] = tk.BooleanVar()
                     self.check_buttons[item] = tk.Checkbutton(self, text=item)
                     self.check_buttons[item].config(onvalue=True, offvalue=False,
                                            variable=self.cb_values[item])
                     self.check_buttons[item].pack()



     if __name__ == '__main__':
 
         root = tk.Tk()
 
         my_list = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
 
         my_cbs = CheckbuttonList(root, "My Checkbox List", my_list)
         my_cbs.pack()
 
         root.mainloop()
```

This is the error I keep getting:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/main.py", line 24, in 
> root = tk.Tk()
> File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/**init**.py", line 2299, in **init**
> self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
> _tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display ":1"

BTW I'm using an [online compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com/) to test this, but I used the python program as well and got the same error.

Comment: If you correct the indentation your code works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message said that it cant find a display where it can open the Tkinter window, if you are using an online compiler it make sense because they often doesn't support GUI applications, you gonna have to run it on your local machine that have a desktop environment running

Comment: I tried the Python 3.11 Application and it gave me the same error!